# Testing app upgrade on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, upgrade, store

Say I have app version 1.0 released on the app store. Then I want to release version 1.1.

I will keep existing data that was copied out of the app bundle and into the app's sandbox. These are some XML config files and a sqlite db the user can write data to. These files could need updates that preserve their existing data.

What is the best way to test an upgrade scenario?

Is there any kind of delegate event that is only called on install?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think testing with AdHoc versions that is dragged dropped in iTunes is a similar upgrade situation.

That's how I tested upgrading our Chess game, so it keeps old and current games on the device.

As for the files/DB I suggest they should contain some version number.

Comment: I assume you run the upgrade checking code each time the app starts? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Not really, haven't changed the "format" that much. I'm using NSDictionaries in plists and new versions only look for and use "new" entries and the code handles "missing" entries gracefully (thus) manage reading old data files.

Comment: Sorry to reopen this ... but how exactly do you drag and drop from Xcode (I assume) to iTunes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use TestFlight for beta testing or preproduction testing.. visit TestFlight.com for more information..